# How to stop following all blogs on Google FriendConnect

Tags: google, google-reader, blogger, friendconnect

Somehow, I managed to add **all** of my subscriptions from Google Reader to Blogger's 'following' service: FriendConnect. This is really annoying, as my 153 subscriptions show up in a list in my Google Reader. I know I can just hide them in Google Reader, but how can I remove **all sites** from my 'Blogs I'm Following' list (without doing it randomly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually just removed them manually. The quickest process I found for doing so was:

Visit http://www.blogger.com/manage-blogs-following.g and log into your Google account if not already.

Click on the **Settings** link next to one of the blogs in the list

[image]

Don't click on **Stop following this site** in the window that pops up. Instead, click on the **Sites you've joined** tab on the right sites.

Here should be a compact list of all of the sites you're following along with **stop following** links.

[image]

Clicking on these links should be much quicker than removing sites from the main list and dealing with a popup window opening and closing all of the time.

Comment: This is the only way that I even know how to remove blogs from friend connect, especially without Google Reader. I didn't realize that this was all you wanted to do! (I don't know of a programmatic way of doing it, but I don't think it is intended to be an application, jut a convenient little tool).

Comment: @FeralOink That's okay, I upvoted your answer anyway

Comment: bungeshea: You are a kind soul :o) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that that happened to me yesterday. I don't know what caused it. I don't mind it, but to undo, try this:

1. Go to Google Reader overview page
   `http://www.google.com/reader/view/#overview-page`
2. Go to the little cog wheel on the left. Click it and select Settings from drop-down menu.
3. You'll get a screen with tabs, that I don't recall seeing horizontally. (It was a vertical list instead). On the Preferences tab, look toward the end, under the **Misc** heading. Uncheck the second box:
   "Show followed blogs from Blogger".

[image: Google Reader tabbed settings view]

This won't unsubscribe you from the blogs. I assume that you don't want to unsubscribe, just not view those blogs in Google Reader. This works if using Google Chrome browser with Google Reader. I haven't tried anything else.

**EDIT**

I read a **[CNET post about Google Reader issues](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57568833-93/google-reader-goes-haywire-for-many-users/)** this morning. Google seems to have addressed whatever the issue was. Maybe it was a minor feature upgrade? I don't remember seeing all these options. Also, I accessed Settings from a link here  `http://www.google.com/reader/` but can't find that now. Anyway, it is working fine for me today.

Comment: Since Google Reader is no more, it is no longer possible to follow the advice of this answer.

Comment: Hello, @AlEverett !! Yes, Google Reader is no more, but FriendConnect lives on. However, the question specifically asked about Google Reader. Should I delete this, or try to answer the question sans Reader? Either alternative is fine. Just let me know, and I will comply.

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned that I can *hide* the blogs in Google Reader, but I want to clean up and remove the blogs completely.